# How to add a cube between two points in python?

Tags: python

I want to add a cube between two points in python.

The result should look like this:

[image]

So i have two world coordinate positions (the empties) and the cube should be places between it. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for. Let me know if I need to fix anything :)

```
import bpy
from math import atan, pi, sqrt

empty1 = bpy.context.scene.objects["Empty1"]
empty2 = bpy.context.scene.objects["Empty2"]

p1 = empty1.location
p2 = empty2.location

x = p2[0] - p1[0]
y = p2[1] - p1[1]
z = p2[2] - p1[2]

mag = sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

if x == 0:
    beta = 0
else:
    beta = atan(y/x)
if (x <= 0 and y >= 0) or (x <= 0 and y <= 0):
    beta = pi + beta 
if mag == 0:
    theta = pi/2
else:
    theta = atan(z/mag)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

gap = (p2 - p1).magnitude

cube = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"]

cube.scale.z = gap/2

cube.location = p1 + (p2 - p1)/2

cube.rotation_euler.z = beta
cube.rotation_euler.y = -theta + pi/2
```

Comment: great, thanks mate! Exactly was i was searching!

Comment: You're welcome! I realized that I didn't handle divide by zero when x = 0, so I set beta = 0 when x = 0 to fix it. This occurs when the empties are aligned vertically.

Comment: thank you again! ;)